# cloudfoundry on openstack iaas - understanding the stack

Tags: cloud-foundry, iaas

I am evaluating cloudfoundry (private cloud option) with Openstack as an IaaS candidate.
I have following setup in mind, but looks like I am missing some connections -

1. I will have OpenStack installed
2. On one VM on openstack (ubuntu 10.4 image), I will install cloudfoundry cloud_controller
3. On other multiple VMs on openstack, I will install cloudfoundry DEAs
4. And this I understand as called a multiple hosts installation of cloud foundry
5. Now when I push an application to cloudfoundry using VMC (with 5 instances request), One of the Cloudfoundry DEA will spawn 5 VMs on itself and deploy/run the app on all 5 cloudfoundry VMs
6. That means I have 5 instances of my app running
7. I can access the app through a single URL and cloudnfoundry controller/router will route the request to one of the running instances of my app
8. Now for scaling the infrastructure, I can reconfigure my openstack instances and restart them with new configuration (i.e. more volume, more RAM etc)
9. And for scaling the application, I can simply add more instances to the cloudfoundry vmc push command

Sorry for the writeup but pls suggest if this is a valid understanding (also if you guys have better options - basically we are looking at a scalable application and infrastructure for developers)

Thanks Much,

Answer (score 2):

Vcap OSS questions are best directed to the [vcap dev site](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vcap-dev) and I would suggest you start there.